# Jaxb: xsi got replaced with ns2 in the root element

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I have used the following code snippet

```
 marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
            Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setSchema(getSchema(xsdSchema));
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper",
            new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
                @Override
                public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1,
                    boolean arg2) {
                    return "tf";
                }
            });
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
            "http://www.xyz.com/tf " + xsdSchema);

        marshaller.marshal(obj, new StreamResult(xml));
```

The output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tf:abc xmlns:tf="http://www.xyz.com/tf" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns2:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/tf schema/myxsd.xsd">
```

As you see i'm getting "ns2" in the place of "xsi".

What i need would be xsi in ns2's place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your namespaceprefixmapper should return the value for each namespace declared:

```
package mapdemo;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JAXBMarshallerExample {

    public static NamespacePrefixMapper val = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {

        private static final String XSI_URI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        private static final String TF_URI = "http://www.xyz.com/tf/whatever.xsd";

        @Override
        public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
            if(XSI_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
                return "xsi";
            } else if(TF_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
                return "tf";
            }
            return suggestion;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
            return new String[] { XSI_URI, TF_URI};
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Output.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", val);

        Output output = new Output();
        output.setId("1");

        marshaller.marshal(output, System.out);
    }

    @XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.xyz.com/tf/whatever.xsd")
    public static class Output {
        String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SorenD, tried your approach. But it is still ns2 in place of xsi.

Comment: Hi @PavanSky. I have updated example with full code. Otherwise, please update with information regarding the setSchema(...) and the object you're trying to marshal.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your implementation of `NamespacePrefixMapper` to do this instead of always returning `tf` from `getPreferredPrefix`